# Page is displaying plain html text instead of rendering the html table

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to display html table by assigning the html text to one variable and returning that variable and passing the html code in an json array format like below.

```js
[{
  "fruit": "apple",
  "flower": "jasmine",
  "capacity": "0",
  "flavor": "jasm",
  "numbers": "1",
  "nic": "1",
  "ram": "4",
  "source": "flower",
  "details": "<table  id=\"details-0\" class=\"table-striped\"><tr><td>type</td><td>static</td></tr><tr><td>template_name</td><td>gold-sti-rh74-stage-use-only</td></tr><tr><td>template_guid</td><td>ec5c9b84c8857bfa91d11d1527250bf7</td></tr><tr><td>flavor</td><td>m1.Small</td></tr><tr><td>num_cpu</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>ram</td><td>4</td></tr><tr><td>num_nic</td><td>1</td></tr></table>",
  "id": 0
}]
```

But when page loads, I am getting the plain html text with tr> etc... and I am not getting the table format. Please help me with this issue.

```
var _list_data = [];
var details = '<table  id="details-'+i+'" class="table-striped">';

          details += '<tr><td>type</td><td>static</td></tr><tr><td>template_name</td> </tr>';
      details += '</table>';

      _list_data['details'] = (details);
    return _list_data;
```

This returns the plain html code in page. I need to make it as proper table format.
we can use v-html in vue js, but this response is sending to library. How can we edit library file by adding v-html, that should not be proper way right? I am confused.

```js
var _list_data = [];
var details = '<table  id="details-' + i + '" class="table-striped">';
details += '<tr><td>type</td><td>static</td></tr><tr><td>template_name</td> </tr>';
details += '</table>';

_list_data['details'] = (details);
return _list_data;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: `return _list_data;` to where? Can you make a working example by updating the snippet I made for you

Comment: its returning to vuejs data table library. From there table is rendering. This one working in virtual machine, cant copy the code and make it working here

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you into a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) rather than {{}}.

```
<div v-html="_list_data[0]['details']"></div>
```

Comment: we can use it, but that div loads from vue data table library. we cant edit library file, right? any alternative way please

Comment: Maybe you should put your .vue in your question. It will more clear what you want to ask.

Comment: Which library you are using?